# Different destructor behavior between vc9 and gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++-2008

The following code gives a different number of destructors when compiled on GCC and vc9. AFAIK when run on vc9 i get 5 destructors showing, which I understand. The + overloaded operator is called, and two object are created, when returned a temporary object is created. This makes destruction of 3 objects possible. When the overloaded = operator is called, one object is created and again a temporary one when returned. This sums it up to five destructs, not counting the three objects created at the start of main.

But when I compile on GCC I get 3.

Which leads me to guess that there isn't a temporary object created when the function is terminated and returned ? or a question about different behavior between compilers. I simply do not know, and some clarification would be nice.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class planetCord {
    double x, y, z;
public:
    planetCord() { x = y = z = 0; }
    planetCord(double j, double i, double k) { x = j; y = i; z = k; }    
    ~planetCord() { cout << "destructing\n"; }
    planetCord operator+(planetCord obj);
    planetCord operator=(planetCord obj);
    void show();
};

planetCord planetCord::operator +(planetCord obj) {
    planetCord temp;
    temp.x = x + obj.x;
    temp.y = y + obj.y;
    temp.z = z + obj.z;
    return temp;
}

planetCord planetCord::operator =(planetCord obj) {
    x = obj.x;
    y = obj.y;
    z = obj.z;
    return *this;
}

void planetCord::show() {
    cout << "x cordinates: " << x << "\n";
    cout << "y cordinates: " << y << "\n";
    cout << "z cordinates: " << z << "\n\n";
}

int main() {
    planetCord jupiter(10, 20, 30);
    planetCord saturn(50, 100, 200);
    planetCord somewhereDark;

    jupiter.show();
    saturn.show();
    somewhereDark.show();
    somewhereDark = jupiter + saturn;  
    jupiter.show();
    saturn.show();
    somewhereDark.show();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GCC is implementing the "return value optimization" to skip temporaries. Set VC9 to Release mode and it'll probably do the same.

If GCC is really good, it is seeing that `temp` inside `operator+` will be default-initialized, just like `somewhereDark`, and can just use a reference to `somewhereDark` directly if it tries to inline the function. Or it is seeing that the pass-by-value is useless and can instead pass-by-reference.

Comment: vc9 produces 4 destructors when set to release mode. I tried to play with different optimizations on the project, but couldn't produce the same result.

Comment: try using initializer lists instead of assignment in the contructor and removing code from the destructor.

I would also use const& for your operators, it's good hygiene.

Answer (score 2):

A permissible but not mandatory optimization for a C++ compiler is to turn the tight sequence:

```
ctor for new temporary object X
copy ctor from X to other object Y
dtor for X
```

into just performing the ctor directly on Y. A really good C++ optimizer can do that across a function clal (i.e. when X is the return value for a function). Looks like gcc is optimizing better. Does the result change as you play with optimization options for the two compilers?

Comment: I couldn't get the results to change, except when I set visual studio to release mode. Tried to set different optimizations and play with the settings, but it stayed the same.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of  of things wrong with your code. Can I suggest you investigate two concepts - consts and references. If your C++ text book doesn't cover these, get a new text book - I strongly recommend [Accelerated C++](http://www.acceleratedcpp.com/)
by Koenig & Moo.

Comment: Already planned to read it after I finish the one I am reading now. Heard my current textbook introduced bad practices, so I was recommended the one you mentioned.

Comment: If your current inspired the above code don't finish it. It's not only bad, it's plainly wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, in GCC, temporaries ARE being made.  They are:

- In operator+.
- Returned by operator+.
- Returned by operator=.

In MSVC (I think; can't test), temporaries are being made as well.  However, some are not being optimized away like GCC does.  They are:

- As a parameter to operator+.
- In operator+.
- Returned by operator+.
- As a parameter to operator=.
- Returned by operator=.

Ironically I think MSVC is in the right here, because I'm not sure if GCC's behaviour is standard.

To make them both behave the same, use `const` references instead of passing the object by value.

Comment: That's a brave claim to make about GCC not being standard. What optimization do you think causes GCC not to be standards conform-ant?

Comment: @York, I don't know the standards near well enough to say.  I just /suspect/ it may not be what the standards say it should (could?) be.

Comment: @Stranger: If you don't know the standard well enough to say, then you definitely don't know enough to make that claim. I suspect that GCC is compliant.

Comment: I said "I think" and "I'm not sure."  I thought that was enough disclaimer.  =X